# regex to determine YYYYMMDD pattern in filename

Tags: regex

Imagine I have the following file names:

> ```
> ZRD0004170011600001020190521.dat
> ZRD0004170011600001020190521.pdf
> ZRD0004170011600001020190521_TC.pdf
> FLX0004170007100001020180630.dat
> RES0004170007100001020180331.dat
> RES0004170007100001020180930.dat
> RES0004170007100001020181231.dat
> RES0004170012200001020180930.dat
> RES0004170012200001020181231.dat
> ZNP0004170120190226.dat
> ZNP0004170120190226.pdf
> ZRD0004170012600001020190520.dat
> ZRD0004170012600001020190520.pdf
> ZRD0004170012600001020190520_TC.pdf
> ```

I want to detect the date pattern YYYYMMDD which is appearing in these files, which can appear immediately before "." or before "_TC".

Can someone help me here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which technology are you using? What have you tried so far? :)

Comment: I'm just needing a regular regex expression which I'm trying to use in https://regex101.com/

Comment: Did you try any of the solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I think you can use this regex :

```
[0-9]{8}(\.|_TC)
```

Is it what you want ?

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks!